# Putting data from Axios call into Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, object, axios

I want the results from the Axios call (where the console.log is) to go into the the Object below it (where location_geo_point: is).  I've tried putting the getCoords function outside of the createElasticSearchJob function and saving the results in state.  however that doesn't work because im passing {location} into the url and it hasn't been declared yet.

```js
function createElasticSearchJob(rowData, getCoords) {
  function getCoords() {
    return axios
      .get(
        `http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=${location}&format=json&polygon=1&addressdetails=1`
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data[0]);
      });
  }
  const {
    country,
    hiring_company: {
      name: companyName
    },
    id,
    location,
    name,
    posted_time,
    posted_time_friendly,
    snippet,
    state: locationState,
    url,
  } = rowData;

  return {
    job_id: id,
    job_title: name,
    location: location,
    num_days_since_posted: posted_time_friendly,
    job_date_posted: posted_time,
    job_date_posted_date_value: posted_time,
    job_url: url,
    job_title_full_from_desc: name,
    job_company_name: companyName,
    job_location: location,
    job_desc_text: snippet,
    job_desc_html: snippet,
    job_source: "ZipRecruiter API",
    job_years_of_experience: null,
    DOC_HASH: id,
    location_geo_point: getCoords(),
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is happening because `location` is undefined inside the `getCoords` method. You can resolve it by the following code:

```js
function createElasticSearchJob(rowData, getCoords) {
  function getCoords() {
    return axios
      .get(
        `http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=${location}&format=json&polygon=1&addressdetails=1`
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data[0]);
      });
  }
  const {
    country,
    hiring_company: {
      name: companyName
    },
    id,
    location,
    name,
    posted_time,
    posted_time_friendly,
    snippet,
    state: locationState,
    url,
  } = rowData;

  return {
    job_id: id,
    job_title: name,
    location: location,
    num_days_since_posted: posted_time_friendly,
    job_date_posted: posted_time,
    job_date_posted_date_value: posted_time,
    job_url: url,
    job_title_full_from_desc: name,
    job_company_name: companyName,
    job_location: location,
    job_desc_text: snippet,
    job_desc_html: snippet,
    job_source: "ZipRecruiter API",
    job_years_of_experience: null,
    DOC_HASH: id,
    location_geo_point: getCoords(location),
  };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The thing you want to do is pretty simple, you can use `async/await` syntax or just using a closure. Try this:

```js
async function createElasticSearchJob(rowData, getCoords) {
  async function getCoords() {
    const { data } = await axios.get('http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=${location}&format=json&polygon=1&addressdetails=1');
    return Promise.resolve(data[0]);
    // It's better to wrap this axios call inside a try/catch block and handle the exceptions.
  }
  const {
    country,
    hiring_company: {
      name: companyName
    },
    id,
    location,
    name,
    posted_time,
    posted_time_friendly,
    snippet,
    state: locationState,
    url,
  } = rowData;

  return {
    job_id: id,
    job_title: name,
    location: location,
    num_days_since_posted: posted_time_friendly,
    job_date_posted: posted_time,
    job_date_posted_date_value: posted_time,
    job_url: url,
    job_title_full_from_desc: name,
    job_company_name: companyName,
    job_location: location,
    job_desc_text: snippet,
    job_desc_html: snippet,
    job_source: "ZipRecruiter API",
    job_years_of_experience: null,
    DOC_HASH: id,
    location_geo_point: await getCoords(location), // don't forget to pass the parameters
  };
}
```